# fails to boot 14.04 (dual boot set-up with Win 7) ... "no partitions"

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, boot-repair

New to Ubuntu. I have been using a dual boot Windows 7 / Ubuntu 14.04 for the past few weeks.  While using Ubuntu today (Firefox), my system "crashed" and I had to power-off.  When I tried to reboot, it wouldn't. After the power on and BIOS, some basic messages appear on the screen (referencing something about an Intel PCI Ethernet card ...).  THe grub loader doesn't appear so I can't boot into Ubuntu or Windows.

I have the image DVD from my original install.  I booted up with that and chose "Try Ubuntu" and then I opened a terminal to get the boot repair disk tool.  It was unable to fix anything (the menu choice for repair didn't even appear) but it did allow me to paste some information on the boot troubles:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/15444232/

I am not sure what to try next (I do have a Windows 7 repair disk but I have a feeling it would be better to get the grub back???)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
**strong text**
I just powered-up again and went into the BIOS set-up and on the first page it says "HDD: none" "HDD1: none".  Does that mean my hard disk is damaged or somehow disconnected?

I also ran gparted form the DVD and the hole disk seems to be unallocated and extremely small (roughly 1 GB).

(Not sure if it helps, but this is a Dell Vostro Laptop, with Intel Centrino 2 processor, 32 bit Windows 7 and 64 bit Ubuntu.)

Comment: Yes, that looks like a hardware failure -- a bad disk, unplugged disk, or failure of the disk controller circuitry on the motherboard. If so, there's nothing you can do in software to fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you, @Rod. I just ran the diagnostics from the BIOS and it indicated "no hard drive detected" so I guess I'll have to try some physical fixes or it might be time for a new computer anyways.  Thanks again.